# turn numbering off, but keep Table of Contents intact?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering, emacs, org-mode

I have a LaTeX template I created for use with Emacs org-mode, to export to PDF via LaTeX using xelatex.

I don't edit LaTeX directly, I just generate from org-mode.

This works perfectly for me except for one thing: it only works when I have heading numbering turned on.

When I turn numbering off in org-mode, by adding this line to my org-mode file...

```
#+OPTIONS:   num:nil
```

...LaTeX no longer recognizes my headings as headings. This creates two problems in the resulting PDF:

1. The Table of Contents is blank.
2. The \leftmark in the heading shows up as "Contents" instead of showing up as the title of the section.

How do I modify these org-mode preferences such that my I can turn heading numbering off in org-mode while still correctly generating a Table of Contents and adding my section title to the header?

I'm sorry, but I don't know enough about LaTeX to make a minimum representation of this. I have no idea where the problem is.

Here are the org-mode preferences in question: 
http://pastebin.com/62Nugpsg

Comment: the `article` class omits all starred headers from the toc.  some other classes (such as `amsart`; there may be others) include them.  since you're not preparing this input directly, it may be to your benefit to try a document class that does include starred headers, or develop a class of your own, starting with a class that otherwise produces your preferred format, and patch in the star-including code from `amsart` or similar.  (none of the `toc*` packages seem to handle starred sections this way.)

Comment: I see. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Another way to turn off numbering of sections, subsections,... in the `article` class is to do `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}`. And the sections and subsections will correctly appear in the table of contents. So, perhaps try with `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` added in the LaTeX file, but without doing `num:nil` from `org-mode`

Comment: I like that idea. I tried it, but the numbers still appear. Is there somewhere in particular I should put that line? I tried it in a couple places, including right at the beginning: (add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
  '("ilija"
"\\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\\setcounter{\\secnumdepth}{0}
\\usepackage{float}
\\usepackage[breaklinks=true,linktocpage,pdftitle={\\@title},pdfauthor={\\@author},xetex]{hyperref}
\\usepackage{algorithm}
\\usepackage{amsmath}
\\usepackage{ifxetex}

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as you and I tried what @jfbu was suggesting in the comments and this worked with org-mode:

Near the beginning of your file, add

```
#+LaTeX: \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
```

Comment: In my case the TOC links do not work properly then, they link to the first page of the document instead of the chapter...